# Minecraft graphic bug after some minutes playing

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I just start the game, start loading the world and after a few seconds, this happens.
I have the graphic drivers up to date and also I did update the java, nothing works.

[image: The game stays just like this]

I tried creative mode, and also I can't see a lot of the block icons!
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had this happen to me before, it's because your computer is still rendering blocks in the distance. Try reducing your graphics settings to Fast instead of Fancy and reducing the Render Distance in Minecraft's video settings.

Comment: Change from Fancy to Fast didn't change anything. Change the Render Distance do change how intense the blue is, but still the problem. Thx anyway for trying to help me.

Comment: Changing from fancy to fast will cause the chunks to render faster, but I guess your render distance was too high for it to make a difference.

Comment: I think have nothing to do with the render, I can't see the icon of most of the block either, as you can see in 2nd pick, I've edited. Thx for your reply

Comment: I think that means that there's something weird going on with your graphics card, you should make a separate question about that second picture and leave the first up on this page.

Comment: @CRACK Also, the key combination F3 + A forces Minecraft to reload the chunks around it.. It can help get things to render back in again (that is something that happens often when using things like FRAPS and OBS to record/stream)

Comment: hey guys, I just want to say you that it was solved by changing mip map levels from 4 to off! thank you all anyway

Comment: @Crack if the mipmap was the problem and not render distance then Ama291's answer was wrong and should not be accepted. You should post your own answer to the question so others can learn properly should they encounter the same problem.